# Python tcp - send only the first SYN

Tags: python, tcp, handshake, syn

I want to open socket session with some web server in python and I want only the first SYN to be sent

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect("www.websever.com", 80)
```

but with my code I can see all 3 way handshake segments,

Is there some way that I can control the segments and send only the first SYN?